# Get Firebase User.ProviderID on auth/wrong-password when using signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an Application that uses Firebase for Authentification.

I allow users to sign in with either Google/Facebook/Twitter or using an Email and Password.

Additionally I have activated within Firebase that Users can only create one account per email.

I want to cover the Following case:

A users signs up with facebook and gets a user account created with their facebook email (e.G. `facebookuser@gmail.com`).

A few days later the user comes back to the app, but forgot that he signed up using facebook and tries loging in with their email adress `facebookuser@gmail.com` and their usual password instead.

The [`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) method throws an `auth/wrong-password` error, as no password was given using the facebook login method but the email does exist.

Instead of showing a useless *"Wrong password or the account corresponding to the email does not have a password set."* error I would like to check instead which provider was used for signing up and reminding the user to sign in with the provider instead.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to exist a method to get the User.ProviderID for a given email or to understand if the `auth/wrong-password` error was given because the user typed in a wrong password or if there was no password given in first place as the user signed up with an OAuthProvider instead.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I have missed the `fetchProvidersForEmail` method.

Just for Reference: *(not the final code I will be using)*

1. Uses `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to check if a User exists
2. If it doesn't it creates it using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`
3. If a user exits, it tries to login and catches errors
4. If the error is `auth/wrong-password` it checks with `fetchProvidersForEmail` if the user has used a Provider to sign up

   ```
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
       var errorCode = error.code;
       var errorMessage = error.message;

       // User not found? Create user.
       if ( errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found' ) {
           firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
               // Handle Errors here.
               var errorCode = error.code;
               var errorMessage = error.message;
               if ( errorCode == 'email-already-in-use' ) {
                   alert('You already have an account with that email.');
               } else if ( errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email' ) {
                   alert('Please provide a valid email');
               } else if ( errorCode == 'auth/weak-password' ) {
                   alert('The password is too weak.');
               } else {
                   alert(errorMessage);
               }
               console.log(error);
           });
       // Wrong Password Error
       } else if ( errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password' ) {
           // Check if User has signed up with a OAuthProvider
           firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(email).then(function( result ){
               // … show OAuthProvider Login Button
           });
           alert('Wrong password. Please try again');
       } else {
           alert( errorMessage );
       }
       console.log( error );
   });
   ```

Comment: The issue with this is that it doesn't actually link the accounts.  It's basically just saying, hey, you actually have a "Google" account under that email address, use that instead.

Comment: Great answer! I think it would be even better if you use a switch case instead of an "if else"-construction. That would make it better readable and understandable. An example can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter